# $f$ is the derivative of some function, prove that there exists a number $\epsilon\in[a,b]$ such that $\int_a^b f(t) dt=f(\epsilon)(b-a)$

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is the derivative of some function defined on $[a,b]$, prove that there exists a number $\epsilon\in[a,b]$ such that $\int_a^b f(t) dt=f(\epsilon)(b-a)$

My work:

According to the First mean value theorem of Integral calculus if $f$ were given to be continuous on [a,b], then the above statement is true. In fact, according to it, condition of continuity is necessary for function to assume its mean value in the interval. The only thing about $f$, given in the question, is that it is derivative of another function. How can I prove $\int_a^b f(t) dt= f(\epsilon)(b-a)$ from this?

Answer (score 4):

You can't prove that $f$ is continuous, because there are differentiable functions with discontinuous derivatives.

You can, however, prove the following: if $f = g'$ is Riemann integrable, then

$$\int \limits_a^b f(t) \, \mathrm{d} t = g(b) - g(a).$$

Now the claim follows directly from the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: Of course. But the point is how would I prove its Riemann integrability?

Comment: @user467745 As I understand, the integrability is one of the hypothesis. Otherwise the claim doesn't make sense, because it involves an integral of a potentially not integrable function. A derivative in general may be not integrable.

Comment: @user467745 If $f$ is the derivative of some function on $[a,b]$, then it is not necessarily Riemann integrable. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function) counterexample.

However, there is a vastly more general notion of integration, called [Henstock-Kurzweil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral#Properties) integration, which resolves this problem. 

With this integral, if $f$ is the derivative of some function on $[a,b]$, then $\int_a^b f(t) \ dt$ is always well-defined, and  $\int_a^bf(t) \ dt = g(b) - g(a)$ where $g'=f$.

Comment: But there are examples where even if $f'=g$,  $\int_a^bf dx\ne g(b)-g(a)$. In fact there are examples where $f'=g$ is bounded, but $f$ is not riemann integrable.

Comment: Consider this example: Let $f$ be defined on $[0,1]$ as $f(x)=x^2\cos(\pi/x^2),$ if $0,x\le1, f(0)=0$. Then $f$ is differentiable on [0,1] and $f'(x)=2x\cos(\pi/x^2)+(2\pi/x) sin(\pi/x^2), if 0<x\le1, f'(0)=0$. Now $f'$ is not bounded on $[0,1]$ and therefore it is not Riemann integrable i.e $\int_0^1f'(x)dx$ does not exist.

Comment: @user467745 Who are you addressing? Both MathematicsStudent1122 and I wrote above that a derivative may be not integrable.

Comment: @Adayah: I was addressing  MathematicsStudent1122 because she/he, in her/his last line had said that according to Henstock-Kurzweil theorem $\int_a^bf(t)dt=g(b)-g(a)$ if $f'=g$. But in the example I gave, this does not hold.

Comment: @Adayah: Could you include the proof for Riemann integrability in your answer, because I am unable to prove the function to be riemann integrable.

Comment: @user467745 MathematicsStudent1122 refers to Henstock-Kurzweil integration, which is an other, stronger definition of integration, NOT a theorem about the usual Riemann integration. Also I could not include the proof for Riemann integrability of a derivative of any function, since in general a derivative may be not Riemann integrable. If integrability of $f$ is not asserted by the hypothesis, the claim in your question is incorrect.

Comment: @Adayah: So, if $f$ can not be proved to be Riemann integrable, then how can I use your answer for my question? Also, however general the notion of integration there maybe, it cannot be generalised for any $f$.

Comment: @Adayah: You may be right. But an incorrect question cannot have a correct answer.